# How to connect a phone line?

Tags: telephone, phone-wiring

I'm trying to connect the phone lines in my new home. I have 2 lines given by my phone provider arriving downstairs in the apartment:

[image]

Then I have 2 `RJ11` cables plugged into to the connections shown above which send the lines upstairs. However upstairs no connection has been made, I just have the 2 line cables. This is the connection I bought:

[image]

Now here are my questions:

**Q1: Do you confirm that on the above pictures, holes 1-8 at the top are for the left-hand connection, and holes 1-8 at the bottom are for the right-hand connection?**

**Q2: Do I need to connect my white/blue wires back into the same holes, or do I need to change their position somehow?**

FYI If I connect my modem directly to either of the connections shown in 1st picture, my internet works, so I know those lines are good :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to connect a phone line?](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/78483/how-to-connect-a-phone-line)

Answer (score 3):

Those are RJ45s not RJ11s. RJ11's only have 4 pins. An RJ11 fits into the center 4 pins of this jack though.

Q1 Whether one is left or right I can't tell but the top is definitely for one jack and the bottom is for the other jack.

Q2 leave your white on 5 and blue on 4 like all the diagrams below. You can use 568A and the orange pair for the second line connected to 3 and 6 that would be the traditional second line color. The phone doesn't care which color you use as long as they go to the other end.

Hopefully it is obvious that you will not be able to use these jacks for data even though they will accept a data plug.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/T568A/B#Wiring

Answer (score 2):

I am unfamiliar with these particular types of connectors but they're some sort of 8P8C connectors. What country are you in?

A1) Not knowing these types of connectors... best way is to just test it out to see which one is left and which one is right. Connect one pair of wires to the top and see which port has signal.

A2) Connect the white/blue to the center screw terminals (marked 5 and 4 as well as 1a and 1b) just like it's done in the first. Line 1 is always in the center pins with blue on pin 4 and white/blue (or white in your case) on pin 5. If you're only using 1 line phones the conductors should always be on the center pins. Depending on what type of wiring standard your phones use additional lines on the same port may be wired differently but that's not something you need to worry about. Keep the same color orientation. Phone should work with most equipment if you switch the white and blue but best to be consistent.

Comment: I'm based in the Netherlands

Comment: @user359650 I thought you used those 4 pin plugs for phones there. Did a search for "telefoon aansluiten" and found some of the 4 pin and some of the RJ45 like you showed. Curious... are those ports just used to send the line to your apartment and then from there you feed it to jacks with the 4 holes or are you using rj11 plugs for phones?

Answer (score 0):

This connector looks like the parallel connection, It is designed for 2 telephones. Usually the DSL service provider provides the ADSL Splitter use the splitter and pullout the connection for your phone and your modem.

> Make sure no parallel connection before ADSL Splitter, as you will get poor phone signal as well as the DSL signals.