# How to connect a phone line?

Tags: telephone

I'm trying to connect the phone lines in my new home. I have 2 lines given by my phone provider arriving downstairs in the apartment:

[image]

Then I have 2 `RJ11` cables plugged into to the connections shown above which send the lines upstairs. However upstairs no connection has been made, I just have the 2 line cables. This is the connection I bought:

[image]

Now here are my questions:

**Q1: Do you confirm that on the above pictures, holes 1-8 at the top are for the left-hand connection, and holes 1-8 at the bottom are for the right-hand connection?**

**Q2: Do I need to connect my white/blue wires back into the same holes, or do I need to change their position somehow?**

FYI If I connect my modem directly to either of the connections shown in 1st picture, my internet works, so I know those lines are good :)